# Spring boot : Repository interface must not be null on initialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring boot version: 1.2.3 (Cant upgrade right now to latest)

Issue: I have Spring data repository, that I have injected into multiple controllers no issue.

Now I have created to converters by implementing org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter. If I inject that repository in only one converter all is good, but since I need that repo in second converter too when I inject I am getting below error. Not sure what is going on, Oliver please help!

...

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'myRepository': FactoryBean threw
>   exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository interface must not be
>   null on initialization! .... Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository interface must not be
>   null on initialization!

Comment: Can you post your second converter code? Also does this happen when you ONLY inject it into the second converter?

Comment: Yes its not specific to any one converter, if I keep in either one its fine.

Comment: Converters are loaded very early in the application context lifecycle. Sounds like that's causing your repository to be initialised too early. A minimal example that reproduces the problem would help to confirm.

Comment: thanks for responding, application is fairly simple, having few controllers , repos, basic spring boot configuration. You are right this issue started only when I added those two converters. If you want to know any specific part of configuration or something I can give details.

Comment: Also wondering, that why that problem of early loading happens when I inject repo in both converters. If I inject in only one converter its fine.

Comment: any solution/updates ?

Comment: As a bad workaround, removing second converter as spring converter (removed SPI converter interface implementation)